# how to can i handle multiple callbacks return values in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to perform sql queries based on the callback results in if conditions but i am unable to write the code .so please provide som information in code

```
app.get('/resell-property', function(req, res) {
        var data = {}
        data.unit_price_id = 1;
        function callback(error, result) {
            if (result.count == 0) {
                return hp_property_sell_request.create(data)
            }
            else if (result.count > 0) {
                return hp_unit_price.findAll({
                    where: {
                        unit_price_id: data.unit_price_id,
                        hp_property_id: data.property_id,
                        hp_unit_details_id: data.unit_details_id
                    }
                })
            }
        }


        hp_property_sell_request.findAndCountAll({
            where: {
                unit_price_id: data.unit_price_id
            }
        }).then(function (result) {
            if (result) {
                callback(null, result);
            }
        });


    });
```

In this how can i write the callbacks for

```
hp_property_sell_request.create(data) ,hp_unit_price.findAll({
                    where: {
                        unit_price_id: data.unit_price_id,
                        hp_property_id: data.property_id,
                        hp_unit_details_id: data.unit_details_id
                    }
                })
```

In that after returning result again i have to handle callbacks and perform this query

```
if(result.request_id){
               return hp_unit_price.findAll({
                    where:{
                        unit_price_id:result.unit_price_id,
                        hp_property_id:result.property_id,
                        hp_unit_details_id:result.unit_details_id
                    }
                }).then(function (result){

                    if(result.is_resale_unit==0 && result.sold_out==0){
                        return Sequelize.query('UPDATE hp_unit_price SET resale_unit_status=1 WHERE hp_unit_details_id='+result.unit_details_id+' and  hp_property_id='+result.property_id)
                    }

                })
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

The promise resolve function takes only one input argument, so if you need to pass in multiple stuff, you have to enclose them in a single object. Like, if you have to go with something like:

```
database.openCollection()
    .then(function(collection){
        var result = collection.query(something);
        var resultObject = { result: result, collection: collection };
    })
    .then(function(resultObject){
        doSomethingSyncronousWithResult(resultObject.result);
        resultObject.collection.close();
    });
```

You can't use Promise all if all of your stuff isn't a result of a promise resolve, you might need to go with something like this.

Disclaimer: The code example is a very poor one, but it explains the concept.

Comment: thanq for the reply @ardil please give some sample code

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to learn about Promises, particularly Bluebird.
You can promisify traditional callback methods.

I would also create model level functions in different files. Here's an example.

**parent.js**

```
const db = require("./connections/database");  // connection to database

const getChildForParent = function (parentId, childId, callback) {
    db.find({parent: parentId, child_id: childId}, "childrenTable", function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }
        return callback(null, result);
    });
};
```

**children.js**

```
const db = require("./connections/database");  // connection to database

const getToysForChild = function (childId, callback) {
    db.find({toy_belongs_to: parentId}, "toysTable", function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }
        return callback(null, result);
    });
};
```

Then in controller you can do something like this:

```
const Bluebird = require("bluebird");
const Parent = require("./parent.js");
const Child = require("./child.js");

// Promisifying adds "Async" at the end of your methods' names (these are promisified)
Bluebird.promisifyAll(Parent); 
Bluebird.promisifyAll(Child);

// Just an example.
app.get("/parent/:parentId/children/:childId", function(req, res) {
    return Bluebird.try(function() {
         return User.getChildForParentAsync(req.params.parentId, req.params.childId);
    }).then(function(child) {
       return Child.getToysForChildAsync(child.child_id);
    }).then(function(toys) {
       // Do something with toys.
    });
});
```

Of course you can do much more with this and this is not the only way.

Also you can use `Promise.all()`. This method is useful for when you want to wait for more than one promise to complete.

Let's say you have a list of urls that you want to fetch and process the results after all the data has been fetched.

```
var urls = [url1, url2, url3, url4, url5 .......... ];
var Bluebird = require("bluebird");
var request = require("request"); // callback version library

Bluebird.promisifyAll(request);

// create a list which will keep all the promises
var promises = [];

urls.forEach(function(url) {
    promises.push(request.getAsync(url1));
});

// promises array has all the promises
// Then define what you want to do on completion.

Bluebird.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    // results is an array with result a url in an index

    // process results.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to solve that. If you need all results of all Requests, when they are all done `Promise.all()` will do that for you. Your basic could look like that:

```
var req1 = new Promise(function(res, rej){
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
    …
    req.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
        res(e);
    })

var req2 = //similar to the above

Promise.all([req1, req2, …]).then(function(values){
  //all requests are done here and you can do your stuff
});
```

You can also use the new fetch api, which creates Promises like so:

```
var req1 = fetch(…);
var req2 = fetch(…);
Promise.all([req1, re2, …]).then(…);
```